# How do I dotnet pack a self-contained dotnet core application?

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I need to use dotnet pack on a self-contained application (a windows service).  I can build it self-contained with dotnet publish.  When I use dotnet pack it will build, but I can't get it to publish.

I can do it in 2 operations - publish then pack.  However, I don't seem to be able to pack just the output from the publish.  The dotnet pack command want a project file name instead of a folder.  Nuget pack, and octo pack, have the basePath option which does not seem to be available withdotnet pack.

Comment: Use Nuget only to publish libraries.

Comment: As far as I am aware, if you use the [--runtime switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x#options), it will be packed as a self contained (assuming that you have set up the project such that it's self containable)